# Matrix gallery resource

Tags: matrices, online-resources

Does anyone know of a comprehensive list of matrix types (including a definition of each type)?

I am looking for something like [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_matrices). **Importantly, it would be useful if there was a simple example of each type of matrix so one could search *visually* for the desired matrix type (hence the word "gallery" in the title).**

Comment: I believe that this is as exhaustive as it's gets.

Comment: @JGab but there is no visual component in that list...

Comment: Have a look at the Matrix Cookbook: http://www.eattardo.com/the-matrix-cookbook/